# OCC gp_Pnt with passed variable

Tags: python, cad

I am trying to write a function which is passed a position as a variable.
The function needs to use OCC gp_Pnt(). How can I pass variable values to gp_Pnt.
I know that gp_Pnt wants a constant but python does not have a constant as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Okay fixed, Had a typo which is why it was not working